# c# how to avoid adding the same product id from textbox.text to listbox

Tags: c#

I have a code here that tells you that, for every product in a bound list called product of a `ProductListSource.DataSource`, I have an if statement that if the `product.ProdID` is equal to the text you have inputted, you should add that on to a listbox. But the problem is I want a limiter... I don't want the same id to be added more than one.
Here's my code demonstrating what I have done so far:

```
private void AddToCartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var product in (BindingList<Product>) ProductListSource.DataSource)
    {
        if (product.ProdID == ProdIDText.Text.Trim())
        {
            CartList.Items.Add(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check in the listbox.items if the productid already exists.

Comment: `CartList.Items.Contains`.

Comment: thanks for that mjwills, my thoughtprocess was fully out of whack dude, i had in the assumption to target product.productid... what i should've targeted was the product itself...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Distinct LINQ extension method to filter products with common product IDs:

```
var productList = (BindingList<Product>)ProductListSource.DataSource;
foreach (var product in productList.Distinct((one, two) => one.ProdID == two.ProdID)) 
{
    if (product.ProdID == ProdIDText.Text.Trim())
    {
        CartList.Items.Add(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution did not work on this code of mine dude, thanks for the help though!